# In a default theorem environment, how to change a certain word into Roman font?

Tags: fonts, environments

Edit: Now I have added the solution as the last part of my question.

---

In a default theorem style, i.e. `\theoremstyle{theorem}`, I have a sentence like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{theorem}
    (1) This is a test. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I want the number "(1)" to be changed into Roman style.
One way I have found is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    $\mathrm{(1)}$ This is a test.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Is there other way to do it? I have tried replace `$\mathrm{(1)}$` by `\textrm{(1)}` but this has no effect, and `\normalfont{(1)}` changes the whole theorem into Roman font style.

---

Thanks for David Carlisle's advice, one way is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    \textnormal{(1)} This is a test. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Also user Teepeemm suggests

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
   {\normalfont (1)}     This is a test. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

David also suggests that I should look at `enumitem` package. This is a solution using the package to produce numbers in Roman fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textnormal{(\arabic*)}]
        \item This is a test.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are probably looking for `\textnormal` but there is no default theoremstyle `\theoremstyle` is not a defined command by default, you must be using some package. Why number by hand, not use `enumerate` `\item` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! I am exactly looking for `\textnormal`. And I have tried ` \begin{enumerate}
 \textnormal{\item }
\end{enumerate}`, but it returned some error. If this does not bother you too much, can you elaborate on how to fix this? (It seems the code block does not work well in comments.)

Comment: don't use `\textnormal{}`  (or any group) around `\item`, you could customise how lists are displayed  using `enumitem` package or other means.

Comment: OK. I will look up that. Thanks for your response!

Comment: You should provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Otherwise this question is likely to get closed as it currently lacks reproducibility.

Comment: @JasperHabicht OK. I have added MWE and the solution.

Comment: `enumitem` is the way to go.  But "\normalfont{(1)} changes the whole theorem into Roman font style" suggests that `\normalfont` is a switch, so `{\normalfont (1)}` would have worked.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you. This also works well. I will add this solution to my question.

Comment: BTW, you should move your solutions to an "Answer" so that they can be voted on separately from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no “default `\theoremstyle{theorem}` and, indeed, I get a warning

```
Package amsthm Warning: Unknown theoremstyle `theorem' on input line 5.
```

and you should as well. The default style when `amsthm` starts up is called `plain` and it's not necessary to call it.

I recommend, for your application, to define your own environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newlist{roster}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[roster]{
  topsep=0.5ex plus 0.2ex, % vertical space around the list
  itemsep=0pt, % no space between items
  parsep=0pt,
  label=\upshape(\arabic*), % the label in upright type
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
The following conditions are equivalent:
\begin{roster}
  \item some condition,
  \item another condition,
  \item a final condition,
\end{roster}
If these conditions are satisfied, we're very happy.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the parameters to suit your taste.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I looked up the document and found I mismemorized `\theoremstyle{plain}`as `\theoremstyle{theorem}`. How come my Texstudio did complie the document with `\theoremstyle{theorem}` successfully without error/warning! Otherwise I could earlier discover my mis-memory.